# Query performance of a range query with date field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, query-performance

I am looking for performance optimization of a query. My goal is to find all documents falling in given date range. The collection is quite big, it has over 6 million documents. So the query is as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date('2018-06-19'), 
        $lt: new Date('2018-06-22')
    }
})
```

It runs for over 10 mins. Is there a way to utilize the fact that the dates are sorted? I mean the documents are inserted at creation time so every document past last document falling into the range will be out of range, but mongo probably doesnt know that and seeks for those documents where dates are already out of range ??

Comment: Is `createdAt` indexed? Is it possible to project selected fields instead of fetching whole document?

Comment: Its not indexed, would adding idex to it require some special care, not to overload DB with such many items ? I know i can add index, reduce the fields and so on, but I was wondering about the date range sorted order specificly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications and its users are looking for is a query performance of within couple of 100's of milliseconds (not 10 mins) for a collection with a few millions of documents. Indexes are used to make these queries run fast.

A range query like above can be made to run fast by creating a single field index on the find query filter's date field. Indexes store the the index key field value and the address to the document in the collection - this is a small amount of data. For a typical collection, query and index, the collection's data and the index need to available (or fit) in the memory (called as working set) to be used effectively. When the query is run, the index is accessed based to the filter criteria and then the corresponding documents.

There is no way to make the query run faster without using an index, with millions of documents (note that it may not matter with a couple of thousands of documents). This can be demonstrated practically, in a *dev* environment with a sample set of couple of million documents, an index on the query filter field and a test run.

The tool to be used for performing this test is generating a [query plan using the explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats). The [explain method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain) has the "executionStats" mode, which gives details like the index used (if any), time to run the query, the index keys accessed, the number of documents returned, various stages of the query execution, etc. The plan stages will tell if the index is used by the query. Typically, a query run using an index will show an indexed scan (IXSCAN), and if no index is used it will be a collection scan (COLLSCAN).

The created index can also be used with other queries, if applicable, and also sort operations. Also, the index can be a compound index (using multiple fields) and if it can be used with other queries.

Also, see [FAQ: Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/indexes/) for more information. Since you already have a large collection see [Index Builds on Populated Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/) for considerations regarding.

The [db.collection.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/index.html) command is useful to find the size of the collection and the index.

In addition to indexing, projection of the required fields only can also affect your query performance.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB cannot utilize "the fact", because it doesn't know what binary documents are stored.

If you search by non-indexed field, Mongodb performs `COLLSCAN` (explained [here](https://medium.com/@zhaoyi0113/how-to-use-explain-to-improvement-mongodb-performance-3adadb1228f1))

**Indexing:**

Since v4.2, MongoDB use an optimized build process that holds the exclusive lock only at the beginning and end of the build process.

Before v4.2, you need to specify `background` option

```
db.collection.createIndex({createdAt:1}, {background:true})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types